# passing referer from the client and getting the headers.referer in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have several sites, I want to check which site call my api, I did this in node.js

```
  const mySite = req.headers && req.headers.referer.split('/')[2]
```

in normal case I will get mysite1.com, myothersite.net but is above code 'safe'? In what case headers is not present? If I call from POSTMAN and don't put header will it cause any problem for above code?

Comment: Referer can be spoofed easily, you shouldn't depend on it for anything security-related.

Comment: `curl -H 'Referer: whateverIWant' yourURL`

Comment: I know it's not secure, at least it did something. My concern will above code crash my server if referer is not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know it's not secure, at least it did something. My concern will
>   above code crash my server if referer is not present.

Yes, it will crash. In your code, if `Referer` is not sent, you will get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

Since you're using express, you can use [req.header()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get), making your code a little shorter & safer:

```
const mySite = (req.header('Referer') || '').split('/')[2];
                 //  ^^^ case insensitive header check
```

I used `req.header('Referer') || ''` to make sure we always get a string, even if the header is not set, so it is safe to `.split`.

Besides being case insentive, the benefit of using `req.header()` is that,  Referrer and Referer fields are **interchangeable**.

Comment: what is the different that making it fall to a string versus Barmar's answer? both worked in my opinion.

Comment: The difference is that one is shorter, which doesn't make it better, but since you're using express, you should use `req.header` or `req.get` function when dealing with headers, and to avoid calling it twice, I use an empty string as fallback.

Answer (score 0):

your code will fail if there's no `Referer` header. You need to check for that before calling `req.headers.referer.split()`:

```
cons mySite = req.headers && req.headers.referer && req.headers.referer.split('/')[2];
```

Comment: typo request.headers